# Phrase to describe the "act of sharing an opinion"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I am writing a research paper on the use of social media for the purpose of terrorism. For one of my supporting statements, I am attempting to describe how social media connects users with similar interests in order to promote people to share opinions, yet I cannot figure out the proper wording for the sentence. This is what I have so far:

> Social Media connects users with similar interests, allowing for the **[act of sharing an opinion]**, effectively increasing the incentive for one to speak out regarding their beliefs regarding contemporary events and issues.

The phrase is on the tip of my tongue, but I cannot seem to think of it. Thank you!

Comment: An act of sharing an opinion can be **sharing an opinion** itself. "... allowing for the sharing of opinions", effectively..."

Comment: '... allowing them to contribute to the discussion' is in the same register.

Comment: to foster opinion sharing. But there is a caveat: I share you opinion means I agree with  you so...maybe one should avoid opinion sharing or sharing of opinions and say allow for exchanging opinions....

Comment: "allowing for the [act of sharing an opinion],"  -> "enabling debate" or perhaps "enabling discussion". I think you need such a phrase, to justify the later phrase "effectively increasing the incentive".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand or agree with the premise.  Social media ***enable*** people to speak out regarding their beliefs regarding contemporary events and issues, by providing a *venue* (or a *vehicle*) for doing so, but I don't believe that it provides or increases any incentive for doing so (unless you count the somewhat narcissistic attention-seeking that seems to go with such media and the feedback that the most controversial contributors tend to accrue).

Answer (score 4):

**Throwing your two cents in.**

Is an idiomatic way of saying, *sharing an opinion*.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I have done with it: Social Media connects users with similar interests, allowing for users to throw their two cents in, effectively increasing the incentive for one to speak out regarding their beliefs regarding contemporary events and issues.

Comment: @TrevorJudice glad I could help.

Comment: @Trevor Judice This is an incongruous mix of registers.

Comment: As StevieV said in his answer, this is an idiomatic phrase and is really too informal for the sentence you are writing, which seems very formal otherwise.

Comment: +1 EdwinAshworth; hope you don't mind my simplifying your comment for a non-native reader...

Answer (score 4):

I think the word you are looking for is **opine**.

From [Oxford Learners](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/opine?q=opine):

> to express a particular opinion

Comment: +1 because this literally answers the title, however I feel that given the entire question, *discourse* is a better choice.

Comment: Great. I switched over to using this word, as it is far more formal, with the added bonus of fluent flow within the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

To share an opinion is to spread the word, i.e. to leave it where it wasn't before.

When social media makes your opinion run among "similar people", then you're not spreading the word, not really sharing your opinion. Beware of it in your research.

Answer (score 0):

This is **discourse**:

> the use of words to exchange thoughts and ideas

Source: [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discourse)

Unlike "throwing one's two cents in", this term is suitable for use in academic discourse.

Comment: … or simply **discussion**.

Answer (score 0):

allowing for the **expression of different views**

I think this matches the register (level of speech) used in the original example.